# Can't logon as Facebook test account on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app with 10 test users. I am developing an iOS app and have setup up the plist file with the Facebook app id as described in the docs.

I run my app in iOS Simulator and click my Facebook Login button which takes me to the Facebook web app. I try to login with one of my Facebook app's test user and I get the error below.

I've seen Facebook Developer videos where the presenter logs on to the Facebook web app from the iOS Simulator. Do you know why I can't?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Check whether the app is in sandbox mode.

Comment: sorry but if you go on facebook (desktop) and try to login with the same account what is the result?

Comment: @Aravind Thanks for the comment, my app was in sandbox mode so I disabled sandbox mode and waited 5 minutes and it still won't let me login from the iOS simulator

Comment: @elio Thanks, I can login as the user on Facebook desktop (firefox) but not from the iOS simulator

Comment: can you log the error?

Comment: It's not my app refusing to login. I've taken my app out of the equation starting the iOS simulator, opening safari, going to Facebook.com and trying to login. The same works outside of the simulator on the Mac desktop Safari. Strange. It's stopping me being able to test my app

Comment: could you try using the simulator to login in settings -> facebook ?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments you've both been helpful in pushing me to test more. See my answer below, pretty sure it's down to aggressive caching in the mobile safari app.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by using Reset Content and Settings on the simulator and restarting it.

When it **wasn't** working I noticed that when I went to facebook.com in the simulator the email address was always pre-populated with my test user. I wonder if the simulator has some aggressive caching, or mobile safari itself.

I suspect that shutting down the safari app would have done the trick too.